# can one be infected with Naegleria fowleri by taking Steam?

Tags: human-biology, microbiology, parasitology, infectious-diseases

will Naegleria fowleri be present in the steam molecules.

Many people take steam from hot water to get relief from sinus.

I read somewhere that Naegleria fowleri gets killed over 70 C. So steam will also kill it?

Answer (score 2):

*N. fowleri* infection can occur after nasal and sinus irrigation, swimming and other exposures to contaminated water. The infectious agent in this case is the trophozoite, not the cyst. Boiling water contaminated with this amoebae kills it, preventing infection. Though it does thrive in warm water (37 C), it doesn't survive in steam (100 C).

Despommier's Parasitic Diseases Ch. 14 discusses *N. fowleri* in some detail. It's also covered in Murray Medical Microbiology Ch. 82, and Cecil medicine Ch. 360. There's also useful study in [The Laryngoscope](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=28224696) on the viability of various pathogens in contaminated water after sterilization methods.

Comment: [To see how these data compare with those obtained in the semiquantitative tests, the ex- posure times for a 99.9% cyst destruction were extrapolated from the survival curves in Fig. 2 and came out as 65, 26, 17, and 3 min at 55, 57, 60, and 65C, respectively.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC242840/pdf/aem00217-0156.pdf). 3 minutes in 65 degree water might be more severe than 100 degree steam. Note that if the habitat of the bacteria surpasses 65 degrees, the sinus area also is hotter than 65 degrees for 3 minutes.

Comment: Ah, this does consider the cyst though, not the trophozoite. My point about inserting boiling hot water/heating your ear up to 65 degree remains valid though.